# Count conditional occurrence of values in multiple cols of one df using another df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have 2 dataframes; the first df_data looks like this:

```
A   B   C
-----------------
0   0   1
1   4   1
1   10  1
2   8   1
2   9   1
3   7   1
3   4   0
4   8   1
5   8   1
6   7   1
9   17  1
9   13  1

...
```

The desired output (df_output) looks like this:

```
Day Zt  Zr
-----------------
1   2   0
2   4   0
3   5   1
4   6   1
5   6   0
6   7   0
7   7   0
8   5   0
9   5   0
10  5   0
11  5   0
12  6   0

...
```

Basically I created a new dataframe (df_output) that only has the Days filled, which represents each day of a given month. I have been trying to figure out how to count occurrences of the values in df_data based on the following conditionals (these conditionals don't actually work since it is pulling from different df's):

```
df_output['Zt'] = (df_data['A'] <= df_output['Day']) & (df_data['B'] >= df_output['Day']) & (df_data['C'] == 1).count()

df_output['Zr'] = (df_data['A'] <= df_output['Day']) & (df_data['B'] >= df_output['Day']) & (df_data['C'] == 0).count()
```

The logic for calculating Zt and Zr in more readable format is (if it were a function):

```
def countZt():
   for each day in df_output['Day']:
   Zt = 0
      for each row in df_data:
         if (df_data['A'] <= day) and (df_data['B'] >= day) and (df_data['C'] == 1):
            Zt = Zt + 1
   return Zt

def countZr():
   for each day in df_output['Day']:
   Zr = 0
      for each row in df_data:
         if (df_data['A'] <= day) and (df_data['B'] >= day) and (df_data['C'] == 0):
            Zr = Zr + 1
   return Zr
```

You can see that the only difference between Zt and Zr is that one is counting those where the Bool (C) was True, and the other is counting where it was False.

The resources I've discovered on this subject only guide on how to make conditionals within the same dataframe, but there is a scarcity/absence of resources that show how to use the value of one dataframe to count the other. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: hey you need to tell us how you want  `zt` and `zr` calculated. we cannot figure that out from your code since you said that the code does not work. What is the logic of creating `zt` for example?

Comment: The logic is the same in my code that doesn't work, but I will edit the original post to make that clear. Basically, Zt is a count of all rows in df_data that meet all 3 criterion, and same for Zr. Thank you!

Comment: can you elaborate on the logistics? what do you mean its the same yet it does not work. Write down the logic not in code format but what you exactly need

Comment: for example how do you get `zt=2` in the first row of the output table?

Comment: for testing the 2nd condition, you look at Day>=B. How is 1>=4? how is the second row satisfying the condition?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I reversed the operators in my explanation here--
zt=2 because <= df_data['A'] is <= the day (in this case, Day = 1) and df_data['B']>= the day, and df_data['C']==1, which is rows 2 and 3 of df_data, hence the count of 2. The original post laid this out correctly, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we could reshape before comparison as shown below:

```
cond = (df.A.values<=df_output.Day[:,None])&(df.B.values>=df_output.Day[:,None])
df_output.assign(Zt = cond.dot(df.C),Zr = cond.dot(1-df.C))
    Day  Zt  Zr
0     1   2   0
1     2   4   0
2     3   5   1
3     4   6   1
4     5   6   0
5     6   7   0
6     7   7   0
7     8   5   0
8     9   4   0
9    10   3   0
10   11   2   0
11   12   2   0
```

Comment: This is completely out-of-the-box thinking that I definitely would not have been able to figure out without a LOT more time! Amazing response, thank you so much!